# NServiceBus 4 Could not forward failed message, queue not found

Tags: .net, iis, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I am having issues after migrating to NService 4 (4.0.4). When a message handling fails, it looks like whole NServiceBus is stopping and not doing any work (messages from MSMQ are not consumed any more). 
After looking into logs, I found the following errors:

NServiceBus.log:

> 2013-10-02 17:49:31.5786 | FATAL | 110 | Fault manager failed to process the failed message with id aa32dce1-f408-4f6d-b448-a24b0118ec27 System.InvalidOperationException: Could not forward failed message to error queue 'administration.worker@localhost.Retries@localhost' as it could not be found. ---> NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to address: [administration.worker@localhost.Retries@localhost] ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, ITransaction transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 60
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 76
>      at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, Boolean serializationException) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Faults\Forwarder\FaultManager.cs:line 48
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, Boolean serializationException) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Faults\Forwarder\FaultManager.cs:line 78
>      at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.FirstLevelRetries.TryInvokeFaultManager(TransportMessage message, Exception exception) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\FirstLevelRetries.cs:line 71InnerExceptionNServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to address: [administration.worker@localhost.Retries@localhost] ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, ITransaction transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 60
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 76
>      at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, Boolean serializationException) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Faults\Forwarder\FaultManager.cs:line 48InnerExceptionSystem.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, ITransaction transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqMessageSender.cs:line 60

MsmqDequeueStrategy.log has lots of:

> 2013-10-02 17:49:32.5579 | ERROR | 57 | Error processing message. System.ObjectDisposedException: The semaphore has been disposed.
>      at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release(Int32 releaseCount)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.Action() in c:\BuildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 227
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

FaultManager.log:

> 2013-10-02 17:49:31.5746 | FATAL | 110 | Could not forward failed message to error queue 'administration.worker@localhost.Retries@localhost' as it could not be found.

I init NSB as follows:

```
Configure.Serialization.Xml();
Configure.Features.Enable<TimeoutManager>();
Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();

var conf = Configure.With(assemblies)
.CustomConfigurationSource(new BusConfigSource(assemblies))
.DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputQueue"])
.CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFault()
.UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister()
.UseTransport<Msmq>()
.PurgeOnStartup(false)
.FileShareDataBus(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NServiceBusFileShare"])
.UnicastBus()
.LoadMessageHandlers()
.MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
.CreateBus()
    .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

EDIT: more info.
I host NSB in IIS. I Publish, Send and handle messages in it.

Web.config looks like this:
[image: Web.config]

Comment: It looks like an error in config as the queue it is trying to send to is quite obviously malformed. Could you post your config?

Comment: I noticed that after disabling SecondLevelRetries things started to working. However I want them running.
Also I tried enabling timeouts and I have similar issues. I get error saying 2013-10-03 13:35:12.8477 | WARN | 59 | failed handling message. NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to address: [administration.worker@localhost.Timeouts@localhost] ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your Init code...

```
.DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputQueue"])
```

I don't see that in the screenshot of your Web.config you provided, but based on the error, I'm guessing you have that defined as `"administration.worker@localhost"`. This should be only `"administration"`.

Endpoint name and input queue are not the same thing. Starting from your endpoint name, NServiceBus infers the names of all the queues from there. So input queue is `{EndpointName}@localhost`. If you're running a master node with an attached worker, the worker's input queue is `{EndpointName}.Worker@localhost`. The Timeout queue is `{EndpointName}.Timeouts@localhost`, etc.

Of course you don't usually have to define the endpoint name in an NServiceBus.Host endpoint, but it looks like you are self-hosting in a web application.

Here's more information on the [NServiceBus Input Queue / Endpoint Name](http://particular.net/articles/how-to-specify-your-input-queue-name) from the docs.

Comment: That is what I was missing in my understanding of NSB (Endpoint != InputQueue). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a funny looking address: administration.worker@localhost.Retries@localhost

you may need to add in your config file:

```
<section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
```

and set

```
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error"/>
```

Take a look at the Error handling sample (if you installed NServiceBus it will be in %ProgramFiles%\Particular Software\NServiceBus\v4.0\NServiceBus\Samples\ErrorHandling)

or in Github https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/develop/Samples/ErrorHandling

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for quick response. However I have mentioned entries.